# I have a SQL Code which runs fine until I run a join with another table for a specific field

Tags: sql, join

I have a SQL Code which runs fine until I run a join with another table for a specific field.

The Code is:

```
select 
 table_A.invoice_id [Column 1]
,table_B.invoice_date [Column 2]
,table_C.bill_number [Column 3]
,table_A.order_id [Column 4]
,(Calculated field) [Column 5]
,table_C.picked_on_date [Column 6]
-- ,table_F.company_name [Column 7]

from table_A
join table_B on tableA.invoice_id = tableB.invoice_id
join table_C on tableA.order_id = table_C.order_id
join table_D on tableA.order_id = table_D.[order]
-- join table_E on table_C.assignment_id = table_E.number
-- join table_F on table_E.carrier_id = table_F.company_id


where 
    table_D.charge_code='ABC'
and table_A.[status] <> 'Cancelled'
and table_A.customer = @customer_id 
and table_B.invoice_date >= @from_date
and table_B.invoice_date <= @to_date

order by table_A.invoice_id
```

And I get the Following results (after entering the Customer ID and Date parameters):

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Column 1  |   Column 2  |   Column 3  |   Column 4  |   Column 5  |   Column 6  |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Invoice57 |   10/13/2013|   Bill 57   |   ord00057  |   Ref00057  |   10/14/2013|
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Invoice58 |   10/15/2013|   Bill 58   |   ord00058  |   Ref00058  |   10/16/2013|
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Invoice59 |   10/16/2013|   Bill 59   |   ord00059  |   Ref00059  |   10/17/2013|
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Invoice60 |   10/18/2013|   Bill 60   |   ord00060  |   Ref00060  |   10/19/2013|
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Invoice61 |   10/18/2013|   Bill 61   |   ord00061  |   Ref00061  |   10/19/2013|
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

But as soon as I join tables E and F (currently commented out) to get column 7 (currently commented out) I get an error that there were multiple or no records.

The reason is that Invoice60 and Invoice61 dont have any assignment_id in table_C (IS NULL) and hence can't join with table_E or table_F. Hence no records.

Is there a way to run a condition that:
IF table_C.assignment_id IS NULL
THEN (leave Column 7 blank or 'NONE')

So, the desired result is:

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Column 1  |   Column 2  |   Column 3  |   Column 4  |   Column 5  |   Column 6  |   Column 7  |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Invoice57 |   10/13/2013|   Bill 57   |   ord00057  |   Ref00057  |   10/14/2013|ABC Pvt. ltd.|
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Invoice58 |   10/15/2013|   Bill 58   |   ord00058  |   Ref00058  |   10/16/2013|DEF Pvt. ltd.|
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Invoice59 |   10/16/2013|   Bill 59   |   ord00059  |   Ref00059  |   10/17/2013|GHI Pvt. ltd.|
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Invoice60 |   10/18/2013|   Bill 60   |   ord00060  |   Ref00060  |   10/19/2013|             |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Invoice61 |   10/18/2013|   Bill 61   |   ord00061  |   Ref00061  |   10/19/2013|             |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I hope I have been able to explain my problem clearly. Please revert to me for any clarifications.

I am very very grateful for your help in advance.

Comment: I suppose you need `left join` instead of simply `join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to use `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
select 
 table_A.invoice_id [Column 1]
,table_B.invoice_date [Column 2]
,table_C.bill_number [Column 3]
,table_A.order_id [Column 4]
,(Calculated field) [Column 5]
,table_C.picked_on_date [Column 6]
,COALESCE(table_F.company_name,'') [Column 7]
from table_A
join table_B on tableA.invoice_id = tableB.invoice_id
join table_C on tableA.order_id = table_C.order_id
join table_D on tableA.order_id = table_D.[order]
left join table_E on table_C.assignment_id = table_E.number
left join table_F on table_E.carrier_id = table_F.company_id
where 
    table_D.charge_code='ABC'
and table_A.[status] <> 'Cancelled'
and table_A.customer = @customer_id 
and table_B.invoice_date >= @from_date
and table_B.invoice_date <= @to_date   
order by table_A.invoice_id
```

And I added in a `COALESCE()` to the `SELECT` list so it returns an empty string instead of `NULL`.

`OUTER` joins (`LEFT`,`RIGHT`, and `FULL`) can return non-joining records, unlike `INNER JOIN` which filters out all non-joining records.

Comment: @ Goat CO:
Thank you so much. I am very grateful. I guess I need to work on my joins fundas.

That worked. But it gave rise to another issue:
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I think one of my subqueries is giving me two records and I need to show both. Not sure what to do here..

But thank you so much anyway.

Comment: @cajetan You don't have a subquery here, is it your `(Calculated field)`?  Might be worth it's own question.  That error indicates a 1:many relationship between outer query and subquery when a 1:1 is required, it may require aggregation within the subquery, or more comprehensive criteria to uniquely match records.

Comment: Yes. I analysed each line to try and eliminate the source of the issue and narrowed it down to this.  

    `,(select total from Table_forExtraCharges
        where [order] = [orders].[order_id]
           and charge_name = 'ABC') [Actual ABC]`

Comment: THANK YOU, THANK YOU SO MUCH. I used the SUM function in that Calculated field which resolved the issue. I am very grateful for your help.    

Clearly I need to practice more. Please excuse my lack of SQL skills.